# AngularJS $watch triggers on page enter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

in my controller, I have a simple `$watch`, but it's triggered when I just enter the page, why ? The alert shows `0___false` so that `$watch` should not be executed.

```
$scope.myScopeArray = [];
$scope.myScopeBoolean = false;

$scope.$watch('myScopeArray.length != 0 && myScopeBoolean == true', function () {
     alert($scope.myScopeArray.length + '___' + $scope.myScopeBoolean);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The watch listener is called when it is registered. [From the angular documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope):

> After a watcher is registered with the scope, the listener fn is
>   called asynchronously (via $evalAsync) to initialize the watcher. In
>   rare cases, this is undesirable because the listener is called when
>   the result of watchExpression didn't change. To detect this scenario
>   within the listener fn, you can compare the newVal and oldVal. If
>   these two values are identical (===) then the listener was called due
>   to initialization.

Like it says, you can avoid this by checking if the two values are identical.

```
$scope.$watch('myScopeArray.length != 0 && myScopeBoolean == true', function (newVal, oldVal) {
     if (newVal === oldVal) {
         return;
     }
     alert($scope.myScopeArray.length + '___' + $scope.myScopeBoolean);
});
```